# How to fetch images from node.js server's folder in URL?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mean-stack, mean.io

Does anybody know how to fetch images from node.js server's folder in URL?
In my folder structure I have folder data and inside there is subfolder img with image. I want to access this image with URL, like this:

```
http://localhost:3000/data/img/default.jpg
```

but when I enter it into browser I always get this error:

> Page Not Found    /data/img/default.jpg is not a valid path.

server.js:

```
'use strict';
/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */
var init = require('./config/init')(),
    config = require('./config/config'),
    mongoose = require('mongoose');
var express = require('express');

/**
 * Main application entry file.
 * Please note that the order of loading is important.
 */

// Bootstrap db connection
var db = mongoose.connect(config.db, function(err) {
    if (err) {
        console.error('\x1b[31m', 'Could not connect to MongoDB!');
        console.log(err);
    }
});

// Init the express application
var app = require('./config/express')(db);

// Bootstrap passport config
require('./config/passport')();

app.use(express.static('data/img'));
// Start the app by listening on <port>
app.listen(config.port);

// Expose app
exports = module.exports = app;

// Logging initialization
console.log('MEAN.JS application started on port ' + config.port);
```

express.js:

```
'use strict';

/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */
var express = require('express'),
    morgan = require('morgan'),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
    session = require('express-session'),
    compress = require('compression'),
    methodOverride = require('method-override'),
    cookieParser = require('cookie-parser'),
    helmet = require('helmet'),
    passport = require('passport'),
    mongoStore = require('connect-mongo')({
        session: session
    }),
    flash = require('connect-flash'),
    config = require('./config'),
    consolidate = require('consolidate'),
    path = require('path');

module.exports = function(db) {
    // Initialize express app
    var app = express();

    // Globbing model files
    config.getGlobbedFiles('./app/models/**/*.js').forEach(function(modelPath) {
        require(path.resolve(modelPath));
    });

    // Setting application local variables
    app.locals.title = config.app.title;
    app.locals.description = config.app.description;
    app.locals.keywords = config.app.keywords;
    app.locals.facebookAppId = config.facebook.clientID;
    app.locals.jsFiles = config.getJavaScriptAssets();
    app.locals.cssFiles = config.getCSSAssets();

    // Passing the request url to environment locals
    app.use(function(req, res, next) {
        res.locals.url = req.protocol + '://' + req.headers.host + req.url;
        next();
    });

    // Should be placed before express.static
    app.use(compress({
        filter: function(req, res) {
            return (/json|text|javascript|css/).test(res.getHeader('Content-Type'));
        },
        level: 9
    }));

    // Showing stack errors
    app.set('showStackError', true);

    // Set swig as the template engine
    app.engine('server.view.html', consolidate[config.templateEngine]);

    // Set views path and view engine
    app.set('view engine', 'server.view.html');
    app.set('views', './app/views');

    // Environment dependent middleware
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
        // Enable logger (morgan)
        app.use(morgan('dev'));

        // Disable views cache
        app.set('view cache', false);
    } else if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
        app.locals.cache = 'memory';
    }

    // Request body parsing middleware should be above methodOverride
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
        extended: true
    }));
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use(methodOverride());

    // Enable jsonp
    app.enable('jsonp callback');

    // CookieParser should be above session
    app.use(cookieParser());

    // Express MongoDB session storage
    app.use(session({
        saveUninitialized: true,
        resave: true,
        secret: config.sessionSecret,
        store: new mongoStore({
            db: db.connection.db,
            collection: config.sessionCollection
        })
    }));

    // use passport session
    app.use(passport.initialize());
    app.use(passport.session());

    // connect flash for flash messages
    app.use(flash());

    // Use helmet to secure Express headers
    app.use(helmet.xframe());
    app.use(helmet.xssFilter());
    app.use(helmet.nosniff());
    app.use(helmet.ienoopen());
    app.disable('x-powered-by');

    // Setting the app router and static folder
    app.use(express.static(path.resolve('./public')));

    // Globbing routing files
    config.getGlobbedFiles('./app/routes/**/*.js').forEach(function(routePath) {
        require(path.resolve(routePath))(app);
    });

    // Assume 'not found' in the error msgs is a 404. this is somewhat silly, but valid, you can do whatever you like, set properties, use instanceof etc.
    app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
        // If the error object doesn't exists
        if (!err) return next();

        // Log it
        console.error(err.stack);

        // Error page
        res.status(500).render('500', {
            error: err.stack
        });
    });

    // Assume 404 since no middleware responded
    app.use(function(req, res) {
        res.status(404).render('404', {
            url: req.originalUrl,
            error: 'Not Found'
        });
    });

    return app;
};
```

Comment: please post your server code. There are a few ways to do this. remember, node is not apache. Anything you want to do you have to enable. You are probably just missing the config to access files.

Comment: actually it was generated by YO mean generator. I found some solutions like this one:var express = require('express');
var app = express.createServer();
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.listen(8080); but I am very new to node.js and do not know how to apply it in my app and every help is very appriciated

Comment: express.static is exactly what i was going to say. You can place that with your existing app.use() statements. I always put that stuff in `app.configure();` but i don't think thats necessary.

Comment: ok so when I have image in the directory data/img(folder data is in the same dir like server.js) the command will look like this: app.use('/static', express.static('data/img'));? because when I put this command into server.js and put this address into browser http://localhost:3000/static/default.jpg I got the same error

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It's like you have already set your data/img folder as a static folder in the line below:

```
app.use(express.static('data/img'));
```

In that case, you should be accessing images placed in the static folder above using below url:

```
http://localhost:3000/default.jpg
```

I will however advice you use Node's global variable  __dirname to indicate the root of the static folder but this depends on where your server.js is located within your file structure.

The js file containing the snippets below is located in the root and I have /data/img folder from the root as well and I am able to retrieve the image using /image name.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/data/img'));
app.listen(3500, function () {
    console.log('Express server is listening, use this url - localhost:3500/default.png');
});
```

See if this helps you.  If it does, make sure you know the reason for using the __dirname global variable name.

SO1